# Adding an Excel workbook from add-in code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with code in an add-into to create a new workbook.

```vb
Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add

MsgBox NewWB.Path & "\" & NewWB.Name

NewWB.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWB.Path & "\mynewfilename", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Stepping though the code, MsgBox will display "\Book1" as expected for a brand new workbook.

Running the macro from the workbook, MsgBox tells me that NewWB is named the same as the add-in file. No new workbook appears on my screen, and the SaveAs no longer creates the file in the directory.

ThisWB is set correctly in both scenarios, and I've tried ThisWb.Application.Workbooks.Add with no change in result.

Project explanation:
I have an Excel file that collects daily data from CSVs and combines it into weekly and overall tables. After three months, Excel starts running out of memory, so I have to start again with a new file. I created a macro to add a new day's data, and am working on one to start a new file based on the current file.

Since there will be multiple files that use the macros, I placed them in the Personal file, but that was causing some minor issues with Excel. I moved the code to an add-in with the intention of having the file load the add-in on startup and unload it when it closes.

Comment: The code works for me but only the first time. After that, it gives me error 1004. I closed the new file, and deleted the new file from the directory and it works again. I suspect the error is due to the `.SaveAs` method not having permission to overwrite the file if it already exists or if a book with that name is already open.

Comment: I always delete the new file after each test so to avoid any problems there. But it seems to me the problem is happening even before the '.SaveAs'. As soon as the workbook is created I ask it what its filename is, and it's telling me that it is the add-in file, which makes no sense. Since it's not happening when I step through the code, I assume it's a problem with the add-in file having focus, which it doesn't during debug, but I haven't found a way to fix that since 'ThisWb.Application.Workbooks.Add' doesn't help.